# openmp creating random number of threads

Tags: multithreading, gcc, openmp

first post!

major edit..

I've got this program for computing a dot product, compiled using gcc with -fopenmp. The problem is, it's not creating the number of threads that I tell it to create. On one computer it will constantly spawn 2 threads, on another 4. Neither of those numbers are the numbers given to them. I'm using the (static, chunksize) scheduling which is an indirect way of being able to choose how many threads I want created by changing the chunksize. I feel like there's something in the runtime that's overriding my instructions, since all the computers are using the same executable. I've also noticed that if I give the program a chunksize that's equal to the total load, it will use one thread but still spawn the same number of threads that it was before. What am I doing wrong?

```
    #pragma omp parallel shared(vector1, vector2, loadsize, vectorsize, final_sum) private(i, threadsum, threadid)
    {
    threadsum = 0;
    threadid = omp_get_thread_num();

    #pragma omp for schedule(static, loadsize)
        for (i = 0; i < vectorsize; i++){
            threadsum += vector1[i] * vector2[i];}
     printf("thread %d reached up to index %d with a sum of %d\n", threadid, (i-1), threadsum); 
    #pragma omp critical
        final_sum += threadsum;
}
printf("final sum: %d", final_sum);
```

Thanks,

Zak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the chunksize represents the amount of work to be performed by the thread. It never controls the spawning of the threads. As you can see from your code, the threads are spawned when you invoke

```
#pragma omp parallel
```

Not when you invoke

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static, loadsize)
```

The static and dynamic scheduling are used to determine the amount of work allocated to a thread, either at compile time or run time. So, don't confuse scheduling to the number of threads.

If you need to control the number of threads, use

```
omp_set_num_threads()
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems like there was a default limit to the number of threads that it would create. I checked them with omp_get_max_threads() and found that I was limited to only 2 threads.

Answer (score 0):

OpenMP has a feature called dynamic number of threads. The run-time is free to decide if the parallel block could execute with fewer threads than specified by `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. Some runtimes have it enabled by default and if so it could be disabled by one of the following ways:

- set the value of the `OMP_DYNAMIC` environment variable to `FALSE`;
- call `omp_set_dynamic(0)`;
- explicitly specify the number of threads in a given parallel region with the `num_treads(#threads)` clause.

`omp_set_num_threads()` as well as the value of the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` sets the upper limit of the number of threads that will be used, but the actual number could still be less than that if dynamic threads are enabled. The default value of `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is implementation dependent: it equals to the number of logical CPUs for GCC and for Intel compilers and equals `2` for the latest Oracle Studio compilers.